# how can i assert all values in a column have specific length in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, assert

I want to write assert statement for checking column 'client_id' has specific length = 12.

```
assert kcell[ kcell['client_id'].apply(lambda id: len(id) == 12 ]
```

or

```
assert (kcell[ kcell['client_id'].apply(lambda id: len(id) == 12])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an actual assertion, run:

```
assert kcell.client_id.apply(lambda n: len(str(n))).eq(12).all(), 'client_id length always 12'
```

Note that `kcell['client_id'].str.len() == 12` will fail if your column is of e.g. *int* type.
My solution works for either *int* ot *string* column.

Comment: `kcell['client_id'].str.len() == 12` - agree, so used `assert (kcell['client_id'].astype(str).str.len() == 12).all()`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `lambda` you can directly apply `len` function using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) and [`pandas.Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html#pandas-series-all)

```py
assert (df.client_id.apply(len) == 12).all(),"Error message"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with `all` for check if all values of column has length `12`, for general solution is added [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert to strings:

```
kcell = pd.DataFrame({'client_id':['012345678912','012345678912']})
print (kcell)
      client_id
0  012345678912
1  012345678912

assert (kcell['client_id'].astype(str).str.len() == 12).all(), 'client_id length is not 12'
```

---

```
kcell = pd.DataFrame({'client_id':['012345678912','012']})
print (kcell)
      client_id
0  012345678912
1           012

assert (kcell['client_id'].astype(str).str.len() == 12).all(), 'client_id length is not 12'
```

> AssertionError: client_id length is not 12